# Import and import as in boost::python

Tags: python, c++, boost, bind

I'm working on a project that has most of it's code in C++ and some in python.

Is there a way to call `import xxx` and/or `import xxx as x` from C++?

I would expect something like this:

```
auto other_mod = boost::python::import("the_other_module");

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(pystuff)
{
    boost::python::module_<other_mod>("wrapping_name"); // I just invented this
}
```

And then in python be able to:

```
from pystuff import wrapping_name as wn

wn.someFunction()
```

Notice that I DO NOT want to do this in python

```
import pystuff
import the_other_module
```

The are objects in `the_other_module` with similar goals and dependencies than the ones in `pystuff` , so I don't want the user to have one without the other.

Also I know I could take **every object** from `the_other_module` that I want to expose and wrap, but I don't want to do one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't so far, I just did:

```
auto other_mod = boost::python::import("the_other_module");

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(pystuff)
{
    boost::python::scope().attr("wrapping_name") = other_mod;
}
```